# Colorful cursor to indicate vi mode in zsh, but fail to reset color

Tags: cursor, vi-mode

I am trying to have cursor color in zsh to indicate normal/insert mode, but once enter normal mode, the color of cursor don't reset to default color in insert mode.

The source are:

```
# color cursor
zle-keymap-select () {
    if [ $KEYMAP = vicmd ]; then
        echo -ne "\033]12;Cyan\e[2 q\033[m"
    else
        echo -ne "\e[2 q\033[m"
        zle -K viins
    fi
}
zle -N zle-keymap-select

zle-line-init () {
    zle -K viins
    echo -ne "\e[2 q\033[m"
}
zle -N zle-line-init
_fix_cursor() {
    echo -ne "\e[2 q\033[m"
}
precmd_functions+=(_fix_cursor)
```

The terminal emulator I am using is alacritty.

---

If I am using zsh inside tmux, the color will change accordingly, but if outside tmux, cursor color don't change.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what terminal emulator you're using but in `xterm`-like terminals, the sequence to set the text cursor colour is [`\e]12;Cyan\a`](https://www.invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Operating-System-Commands:OSC-Ps;Pt-ST:Ps-=-1-2.1017).

And the one to reset it to its default is [`\e]112\a`](https://www.invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Operating-System-Commands:OSC-Ps;Pt-ST:Ps-=-1-1-2.1075)

[`\e[2 q`](https://www.invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Functions-using-CSI-_-ordered-by-the-final-character-lparen-s-rparen:CSI-Ps-SP-q:Ps-=-4.1ED7) is to set its shape as a *steady block*.

`\e[m` resets all text rendering attributes (bold, underline, standout, foreground, background colours...) to default. It shouldn't be needed if you have a sane prompt string definition.

**edit**, `alacritty` (which you've now confirmed was the terminal you used) [does support that `\e]12;color\a` escape sequence](https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty/blob/refs/tags/v0.12.0/alacritty_terminal/src/ansi.rs#L1035), but does not support specifying colours by name, only in `#XXX`, `#XXXXXX` or `rgb:XX/XX/XX` format (using its own limited [`xparse_color`](https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty/blob/refs/tags/v0.12.0/alacritty_terminal/src/ansi.rs#L33), I guess it can't call X11's `XParseColor()` as it is meant to be cross-platform), so you'd need to replace `Cyan` with `#0ff`, `#00ffff` or `rbg:0/ff/ff` there (which should also be supported by terminals that call `XParseColor()`).

The reason it works in `tmux` (newer versions only) is that `tmux` actually translates that `\e]12;Cyan\a` to `\e]12;rgb:00/ff/ff\a` for the host terminal which you can observe if you capture its output with `script` for instance.

So:

```
_reset_cursor_color() printf '\e]112\a'

zle-keymap-select() {
    if [[ $KEYMAP = vicmd ]]; then
        printf '\e]12;#0ff\a'
    else
        _reset_cursor_color
    fi
}
zle -N zle-keymap-select

zle-line-init() zle -K viins
zle -N zle-line-init

precmd_functions+=(_reset_cursor_color)
```

Comment: Thank you, it works!

Comment: I have the same setting on linux, but it doesn't work

Comment: @Solarisending, that would depend on the terminal emulator rather than OS. Those sequences appear to be supported by xterm, rxvt, vte based ones, and tmux provided the host terminal supports it, but not konsole or GNU screen or Linux VGA virtual consoles for instance. What terminal emulator are you using?

Comment: @Solarisending, sorry I had missed that you had clarified which terminal emulator you used. See edit.